# multiply two data.tables, keep all possibilities

Tags: r, data.table

I cannot find a duplicate as of now.

My problem is the following:

I have two `data.tables`. One with two columns (featurea, count), another with three columns (featureb, featurec, count). I want to multiply (?), in order so that I have a new `data.table` with all the possibilities. The trick is that these features do not match, so therefore `merge` solutions might not do the trick.

MRE as follows:

```
# two columns
DT1 <- data.table(featurea =c("type1","type2"), count = c(2,3))

#       featurea count
#1:    type1     2
#2:    type2     3

#three columns
DT2 <- data.table(origin =c("house","park","park"), color =c("red","blue","red"),count =c(2,1,2))

#   origin color count
#1:  house   red     2
#2:   park  blue     1
#3:   park   red     2
```

My expected result, in this case, is a `data.table` as follows:

```
> DT3
   origin color featurea total
1:  house   red    type1     4
2:  house   red    type2     6
3:   park  blue    type1     2
4:   park  blue    type2     3
5:   park   red    type1     4
6:   park   red    type2     6
```

Comment: Would `DT2[, .(featurea = DT1[["featurea"]], 
        count = count * DT1[["count"]]), by = .(origin, color)]` be sufficiently efficient?

Comment: @Roland seems so, and that sounds the best answer so you should post it as such

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be one way. First, I expanded rows in `DT2` with `expandRows()` in the `splitstackshape` package. Each row is repeated twice since I specified `count = 2, count.is.col = FALSE`. Then, I took care of the multiplication and created a new column called `total`. At the same time, I created a new column for `featurea`. Finally, I dropped `count`.

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

expandRows(DT2, count = nrow(DT1), count.is.col = FALSE)[,
    `:=` (total = count * DT1[, count], featurea = DT1[, featurea])][, count := NULL]
```

EDIT

If you do not want to add another package, you can try David's idea in his comment.

```
DT2[rep(1:.N, nrow(DT1))][,
   `:=`(total = count * DT1$count, featurea = DT1$featurea, count = NULL)][]



#   origin color total featurea
#1:  house   red     4    type1
#2:  house   red     6    type2
#3:   park  blue     2    type1
#4:   park  blue     3    type2
#5:   park   red     4    type1
#6:   park   red     6    type2
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah I agree with you. If the OP provides a more detailed example, this idea needs a revision. `nrow(DT1)` is a good idea.

Comment: @jazzurro what would be needed for a more thorough example? My dataset is much larger than this, and does not have the same column names. I still upvoted, though

Comment: @erasmortg I did not meant that I'd need the whole data set. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I initially defined groups by `origin`. But I think groups should be defined by `origin' and `color`. Maybe this is something the OP had in his/her mind.

Comment: @DavidArenburg it does work, but not in this context, as I cannot have any extra libraries at the moment, your data.table proposed solution I can implement right away, if you'd like to add as an answer

Comment: @DavidArenburg True. `by` is not necessary. Thanks for your help. I'll edit that. As the OP prefers your solution, you want to drop your idea as an answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Got it. I'll add your contribution to my idea above.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for that. I'll revise the idea. :)

Answer (score 8):

Please test on larger data, I'm not sure how optimized this is:

```
DT2[, .(featurea = DT1[["featurea"]], 
        count = count * DT1[["count"]]), by = .(origin, color)]
#   origin color featurea count
#1:  house   red    type1     4
#2:  house   red    type2     6
#3:   park  blue    type1     2
#4:   park  blue    type2     3
#5:   park   red    type1     4
#6:   park   red    type2     6
```

It might be more efficient to switch it around if `DT1` has less groups:

```
DT1[, c(DT2[, .(origin, color)], 
        .(count = count * DT2[["count"]])), by = featurea]
#   featurea origin color count
#1:    type1  house   red     4
#2:    type1   park  blue     2
#3:    type1   park   red     4
#4:    type2  house   red     6
#5:    type2   park  blue     3
#6:    type2   park   red     6
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

DT1 <- data.table(featurea =c("type1","type2"), count = c(2,3))
DT2 <- data.table(origin =c("house","park","park"), color =c("red","blue","red"),count =c(2,1,2))
```

Create a dummy column to inner join on (for me its `key`):

```
inner_join(DT1 %>% mutate(key=1), 
          DT2 %>% mutate(key=1), by="key") %>% 
mutate(total=count.x*count.y) %>% 
select(origin, color, featurea, total) %>% 
arrange(origin, color)
```